# In Winter '20 the Individual to ContactPointTypeConsent is not navigable anymore. Is this a defect or intended behaviour?

Tags: npsp, individual

We have a lightning component showing the consents an Individual has given on the Contact Record Page. After the Winter '20 release we observe a regression, the consent information of the Individual can not be loaded anymore with the SOQL query we have been using before.

The component is loading the consent information using a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Individuals) FROM Individual
```

In Summer '19 this queried the Individual together with all related ContactPointTypeConsent records.

In Winter '20 this fails because Individuals is not recognized as a relationship name.

Looking at the schema definition in Summer '19:
[image: Relationship definition in Summer '19]

and in Winter '20:
[image: Relationship definition in Winter '20]

I could not find anything in the Winter '20 Release Notes that indicates that this is an intentional change.

Is this a platform defect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been accepted as a regression in Winter '20 release (Salesforce Support Case #24171706). A fix has been rolled out in release 222.11.